# Calculating percentages of a sum over n rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df looking like below. It has Costs for each Month 1-12. I want to create a new column with the percentages of the Costs' sum over every 12 rows (Month 1-12). So it would take the sum of 12 rows and calculate the percentage from the value in Costs.
I really have no idea where to even start with this. Thanks for any help!

Input:

```
| Name     | Month  | Costs |
|----------|--------|-------|
| Painting | 1      | 1000  |
| Painting | 2      | 0     |
| Painting | 3      | 0     |
| Painting | 4      | 0     |
| Painting | 5      | 1000  |
| Painting | 6      | 0     |
| Painting | 7      | 0     |
| Painting | 8      | 0     |
| Painting | 9      | 1000  |
| Painting | 10     | 0     |
| Painting | 11     | 0     |
| Painting | 12     | 1000  |
| Repair   | 1      | 0     |
| Repair   | 2      | 0     |
| Repair   | 3      | 0     |
| Repair   | 4      | 2500  |
| Repair   | 5      | 0     |
| Repair   | 6      | 0     |
| Repair   | 7      | 5000  |
| Repair   | 8      | 0     |
| Repair   | 9      | 0     |
| Repair   | 10     | 2500  |
| Repair   | 11     | 0     |
| Repair   | 12     | 0     |
```

Wanted output:

```
| Name     | Period | Costs | Percentages |
|----------|--------|-------|-------------|
| Painting | 1      | 1000  | 25%         |
| Painting | 2      | 0     | 0%          |
| Painting | 3      | 0     | 0%          |
| Painting | 4      | 0     | 0%          |
| Painting | 5      | 1000  | 25%         |
| Painting | 6      | 0     | 0%          |
| Painting | 7      | 0     | 0%          |
| Painting | 8      | 0     | 0%          |
| Painting | 9      | 1000  | 25%         |
| Painting | 10     | 0     | 0%          |
| Painting | 11     | 0     | 0%          |
| Painting | 12     | 1000  | 25%         |
| Repair   | 1      | 0     | 0%          |
| Repair   | 2      | 0     | 0%          |
| Repair   | 3      | 0     | 0%          |
| Repair   | 4      | 2500  | 25%         |
| Repair   | 5      | 0     | 0%          |
| Repair   | 6      | 0     | 0%          |
| Repair   | 7      | 5000  | 50%         |
| Repair   | 8      | 0     | 0%          |
| Repair   | 9      | 0     | 0%          |
| Repair   | 10     | 2500  | 25%         |
| Repair   | 11     | 0     | 0%          |
| Repair   | 12     | 0     | 0%          |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `transform`

```
df['PCT']=df['Costs']/df.groupby('Name')['Costs'].transform('sum')
df
Out[98]: 
        Name  Month  Costs   PCT
0   Painting      1   1000  0.25
1   Painting      2      0  0.00
2   Painting      3      0  0.00
3   Painting      4      0  0.00
4   Painting      5   1000  0.25
5   Painting      6      0  0.00
6   Painting      7      0  0.00
7   Painting      8      0  0.00
8   Painting      9   1000  0.25
9   Painting     10      0  0.00
10  Painting     11      0  0.00
11  Painting     12   1000  0.25
12    Repair      1      0  0.00
13    Repair      2      0  0.00
14    Repair      3      0  0.00
15    Repair      4   2500  0.25
16    Repair      5      0  0.00
17    Repair      6      0  0.00
18    Repair      7   5000  0.50
19    Repair      8      0  0.00
20    Repair      9      0  0.00
21    Repair     10   2500  0.25
22    Repair     11      0  0.00
23    Repair     12      0  0.00
```

Comment: This worked great. Do you know how I can incorporate a case to avoid division through zeros? So in case the sum equals to zero, whole argument should just equal to zero

Comment: s = df.groupby('Name')['Costs'].transform('sum')
df['PCT']=np.where(s==0,0,df['Costs']/s)